# Is clang really adding vectors optimally in this C/C++ example?

Tags: c++, x86, clang, compiler-optimization, calling-convention

I have the following C/C++ code:

```cpp
#define SIZE 2

typedef struct vec {
    float data[SIZE];
} vec;

vec add(vec a, vec b) {
    vec result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        result.data[i] = a.data[i] + b.data[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

I was wondering how clang would optimize this vector addition and the compiler output surprised me, as it looks quite unoptimal. This is at `-O3` and with `-march=skylake`.  ([Godbolt with clang 10.1](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:2,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:2,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:2),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+SIZE+2%0A%0Atypedef+struct+vec+%7B%0A++++float+data%5BSIZE%5D%3B%0A%7D+vec%3B%0A%0Avec+add(vec+a,+vec+b)+%7B%0A++++vec+result%3B%0A++++for+(size_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+SIZE%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++++++result.data%5Bi%5D+%3D+a.data%5Bi%5D+%2B+b.data%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+result%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.09067657101676,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1001,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3++-Wall+-march%3Dskylake+-ffast-math%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+10.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.90932342898324,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

```
add(vec, vec):                          
        vaddss  xmm2, xmm0, xmm1          # res[0] = a[0] + b[0]
        vmovss  dword ptr [rsp - 8], xmm2 # mem[1] = res[0]
        vmovshdup       xmm0, xmm0        # a[0] = a[1]
        vmovshdup       xmm1, xmm1        # b[0] = b[1]
        vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, xmm1          # a[0] = a[0] + b[0]
        vmovss  dword ptr [rsp - 4], xmm0 # mem[0] = a[0]
        vmovsd  xmm0, qword ptr [rsp - 8] # xmm0 = mem[0],mem[1],zero,zero
        ret
```

From the looks of it, `a` and `b` are stored in `xmm0` and `xmm1` respectively. However, only the lowest single-precision float in these registers is being used for addition. This leads to two separate additions. Why isn't `vaddps` used instead, which would allow for adding both values simultaneously?

The only thing I could come up with is that clang tries to preserve the higher two floats in the xmm registers. This is why I also tried increasing `SIZE` to `4`, but now I get:

```
add(vec, vec):      
        vaddps  xmm0, xmm0, xmm2
        vaddps  xmm1, xmm1, xmm3
        vmovlhps        xmm0, xmm0, xmm1 
        vmovaps xmmword ptr [rsp - 24], xmm0
        vmovsd  xmm0, qword ptr [rsp - 24] 
        vmovsd  xmm1, qword ptr [rsp - 16]
        ret
```

So for whatever reason, clang now doesn't even use the highest two floats and spreads the vectors between `xmm0` to `xmm3`. An `xmm` register is 128 bits large, so it should be able to fit all four floats. Then this code would be much simpler and only a single addition would be necessary.

(See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qMvsoP))

Comment: there's no such thing as C/C++. They're different languages and you should choose only one

Comment: that doesn't mean C and C++ are the same languages and you're allowed to tag both. [Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252430/995714)

Comment: I am seeing good arguments brought up in favor of tagging some questions C/C++ in the thread you posted, such as no C++-specific features being used. That's exactly the case here.

Comment: Clang may be being cautious to avoid slowdowns from subnormals in the unused high elements.  The store/reload is total garbage for latency, though, guaranteed store-forwarding stall.  The 4-element case is limited by how the calling convention passes FP structs; that's not clang's choice for global functions.  And BTW, this code compiles to the same asm as C or C++, so it's really about compiler back-ends and calling conventions and barely needs either C or C++ tags, but just pick one and it's fine.

Comment: And BTW, x86-64 System V ABI allows the high parts of the input and retval registers to be non-zero, so yes `vaddps` would be legal, and with `-ffast-math` (so you can assume FTZ and DAZ) very clearly better.

Comment: Note the GCC 10.2's asm output is hilariously bad, too (https://godbolt.org/z/vdPYnP), `vmovq` transferring the structs to integer to unpack the high halves with `shr`, then transfer back to add, then another round trip of the result to merge into a 64-bit value with integer shift/or, and back to XMM again for the calling convention.  Like just totally braindead.  **But GCC trunk optimizes it to `vaddps` / `ret`** (even without `-ffast-math`), so the missed optimization bug is fixed.

Comment: Are better calling conventions theoretically possible when internal linkage is being used? I can't really test that with compiler explorer. Also, where are the calling conventions that clang uses defined? I have seen some differences between clang and gcc in the past, so I was wondering why that is.

Comment: If you want people to see replies, make sure you notify them, like @J.Schultke, unless you're commenting under *their* post.  I only happened to have a 2nd look at this one and see your comment.  Anyway yes, a private clone (for constant propagation or other inter-procedural optimization) can use a custom calling convention.  It would be legal to do that even for the normal-named asm definition of a `static` function, but I don't think gcc / clang do that.

Comment: Godbolt uses GCC / Clang targeting GNU/Linux, thus the x86-64 System V ABI defines the calling convention.  The only difference I'm aware of between GCC and clang's calling convention is that clang relies on its callers to sign- or zero-extend narrow integer args to 32-bit (which is undocumented but de-facto standard behaviour):  [Is a sign or zero extension required when adding a 32bit offset to a pointer for the x86-64 ABI?](//stackoverflow.com/a/36760539) GCC and clang both do it, only clang makes callees that depend on it.  ICC doesn't do it at all, so ICC code can't safely call clang

Comment: Generally compilers don't bother inventing a custom calling convention for internal linkage functions. Inlining can certainly help, though, as well as using SSE data types like __m128.